# Restoring a database in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I did a database restore in Azure and now have 2 databases. The original and the restored one with a suffix added to the name.

How do I copy the restored one over the original one?

I do not want to update the connection string in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know for sure,both have same data..try below steps

1.Rename old database to some other name
2.Rename restored database name to desired one as per config
3.drop or archive for some days the currently renamed database

You can do the renaming part through `SSMS`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure Azure does not support renaming databases. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Wow you are right! That makes it so much easier then I expected. Thanks!